# undefined method each for nil: NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I add a new ID through the web form, I get the weather for a new city. But if ID is wrong, I get:

> "undefined method `each 'for nil: NilClass"...

Tell me, please, how to check the server's response and show the message" Did you enter the wrong ID "?

For example, response to the wrong ID:

```
{"cod":"404","message":"City not found: 605856"}
```

my_form:

```
<%= form_tag("search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Go") %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
@array = [703448,6058560,1819729] # ID cities

if params[:q].nil?
  @cities = @array.join(",")
else
  @array = @array << params[:q]
  @cities = @array.join(",")
end

@lookup = Weather.call(@cities)
```

model:

```
class Weather
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?appid=***********************
  format :json

  #call the api with HTTParty and parse the JSON response 
  def self.call list_ids
    response = HTTParty.get(base_uri + '&id=' + list_ids)
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    list = body["list"]
  end
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error? any backtrace?

Comment: list.each do |l| http://pix.academ.info/img/2017/07/12/5fe682a4ea2afa56e21fe6b66f5fc14d.png

Comment: The `list` is nil. What is the `response`? Try inspecting it and show us the result.

Comment: post `body` output

Comment: oh, gosh... how to do it? :(

Comment: @Boris just `p` before `list` like `p body` and you will see the output in console, copy it and paste it here

Comment: Rails.logger.debug response.body : https://pastebin.com/H16cRNfa  I really look forward to your comments, thank you.

Comment: If this helps, I can clone the app to heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard method `#fetch`for this purpose:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-fetch

```
a = [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ]
a.fetch(1)               #=> 22
a.fetch(-1)              #=> 44
a.fetch(4, 'cat')        #=> "cat"
a.fetch(100) { |i| puts "#{i} is out of bounds" }
                         #=> "100 is out of bounds"
```

Also there is a method `#try` or even better `&.` to prevent nil error. Here are some examples:

http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: body.fetch('list'){[]}.compact This solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Boris glad to hear it )

Answer (score 0):

Debug information inside "def self.cal" would be really useful:

`Rails.logger.debug response.body`

Then you can understand how to parse it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=nil
puts a[:ram]
result: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

To avoid this type of error  you can create on nil_class.rb file and keep it in initializers folder in your Rails app.

```
class NilClass
    def method_missing(method, *args)
        ""
    end
end
a=nil

puts a[:ram]
result : ''
```

We can overwrite to avoid errors.